# Perl statement seems executed, but somehow is not

Tags: perl, conditional-statements, optional-parameters

Possibly this is a stupid question, but I fail to see the problem (while assuming there must be one):

I wrote some code; here's an extract:

```perl
use Getopt::Std;
my %options;
if (getopts('hty', \%options)) {
    my @opts = split(//, 'hty');

    @options{@opts} = (1, 1, 1)
        if (scalar (grep { defined } @options{@opts}) == 0);
    something()
      if ($options{'h'});
    #...
}
```

The intention of the code is to define all three options as set if none of the three options was set.
However the code seems to be executed even of one option was set (`-h`), but also the final value is not what I expected.
See this fragment of a debugger session:

```perl
DB<2> x %options
0 'h'
1 1
####: so `-h` was set
DB<3> n
main::(otptest.pl:298): if (scalar (grep { defined } @options{@opts}) == 0);
DB<3> n
main::(otptest.pl:297): @options{@opts} = (1, 1, 1)
###: surprisingly the assignment seems to be executed as well
DB<3> x %options
0 'y'
1 undef
2 'h'
3 1
4 't'
5 undef
###: However at the end the values are not `1` as expected, but `undef`
```

Obviously the program logic is broken by that behavior.
Where is the bug?
Could it be a bug in Perl 5.18.2 itself?

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are seeing with perl 5.34

Comment: Re "*However the code seems to be executed even of one option was set*", No. If that was the case, all three would have `1` for value.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, Try again? While 5.34 identifies the statement being executed a little more clearly (but still far from perfect), the result is still the same. You used `perl -d a.pl -h`, right?

Comment: @ikegami: with "not reproduce" I referred to the wrong statement shown as executed, i.e. *"the code seems to be executed even of one option was set ... However at the end the values are not `1` as expected, but `undef`"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result you're seeing is due to autovivification of all the elements in the grep:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %options = qw(h 1);
print Dumper \%options;
print "empty\n" if  (scalar (grep { defined } @options{qw(h t y)}) == 0);
print Dumper \%options;
```

Which outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'h' => '1'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'y' => undef,
          'h' => '1',
          't' => undef
        };
```

grep aliases `$_` to each of its arguments in turn, meaning that it is possible to modify the args by assigning to `$_`. Because of this, perl regards the arguments as being used in lvalue context, and autovivifies the missing elements `$options{t}` and `$options{y}`.

Comment: So "reading" a non-existing hash element does not bring it to life, just as querying an unexisting element with `defined`, but passing a stream of defined and undefined elements into grep will make them "come into existence" (autovivification)? And that is not because `$_` *is* modified, but because it *could be* modified? Rather confusing IMHO.

Comment: Well, look at it this way - on each grep iteration, `$_` is aliased to the next scalar in the argument list - this is grep's documented behaviour. If `$options{y}` doesn't exist, what scalar should perl alias `$_` to? And if `$_` subsequently gets modified, would you expect `$options{y}` to get created and modified too? Actually it is possible to defer creation by using a temporary proxy object as the argument, and this is in fact done by perl when calling a function. But that's quite expensive and isn't done for map, grep, for, etc.

Comment: OK, may assumption was that `@options{@opts}` would only return existing elements, that is the number would be at most `scalar @opts`. But in fact the number of elements seems to be exactly `scalar @opts`, causing vivification as a side of `grep` effect, too.

Answer (score 2):

> *However the code seems to be executed even of one option was set*

No. If that was the case, all three would have `1` for value.

> *Could it be a bug in Perl 5.18.2 itself?*

There is a bug, and it's the incorrect reporting of what code is being executed. When it says it's executing `@options{@opts} = (1, 1, 1)`, it's actually executing `defined` (the `grep` block). That's why it executes it 3 times.

```
  DB<1> n
main::(a.pl:7):         if (scalar (grep { defined } @options{@opts}) == 0);
  DB<1> n
main::(a.pl:6):     @options{@opts} = (1, 1, 1)     <-- actually `defined`
  DB<1> n
main::(a.pl:6):     @options{@opts} = (1, 1, 1)     <-- actually `defined`
  DB<1> n
main::(a.pl:6):     @options{@opts} = (1, 1, 1)     <-- actually `defined`
  DB<1> n
main::(a.pl:8):     something()
main::(a.pl:9):       if ($options{'h'});
  DB<1>
```

> *the final value is not what I expected*

The values are `undef` because the `grep` arg list is evaluated in lvalue context for performance and/or to allow stuff like

```perl
++$_ for grep { ... } ...;
```

This vivifies the hash elements.  If that's undesirable, it can be avoided by using

```perl
... if !grep { defined( $options{$_} ) } @opts;
```